# Why Fido blocked in web bluetooth but not USB

Tags: bluetooth, usb, fido-u2f, webauthn, fido

FIDO is blocked in web-bluetooth due to system-wide pairing poses security risks [[source]](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/registries/blob/master/gatt_blocklist.txt), which I can understand but not entirely sure why the extend to block it. A good ble token design can possible overcome the issue (button on token...etc).

But when it comes to usb token why is it not consider as a same level of risk too [[source]](https://www.chromium.org/security-keys) and block the access, isn't usb system-wide pairing too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Specifications block FIDO devices:

- [Web Bluetooth Blocklist](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/registries/blob/master/gatt_blocklist.txt)
- [WebUSB Blocklist](https://github.com/WICG/webusb/blob/master/blocklist.txt)

Related Chromium implementation details:

- [Bluetooth Blocklist](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/bluetooth/bluetooth_blocklist.cc?type=cs&q=BluetoothBlocklist::PopulateWithDefaultValues&g=0&l=141)
- [USB Blocklist](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/usb/usb_blocklist.cc?type=cs&q=%22UsbBlocklist::Entry+kStaticEntries%22&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=60)
- [USB Class Restrictions](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/webusb/usb_device.cc?sq=package:chromium&dr&q=%220x0B,++//+Smart+Card%22&g=0&l=569)